# How to get sourcemaps out of Angular2 component styleUrls

Tags: css, angular, sass, gulp, source-maps

i'm developing my first Angular2 app with Typescrypt. Here is an example of Component:

**home.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent {
}
```

Since i have to process SASS files to get component-specific CSS, i created the following [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task:

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('create:styles', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src('src/app/**/*.scss')
             .pipe(sourcemap.init())
             .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
             .pipe(sourcemap.write())
             .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/app/'));
});
```

As you can see i'm using [sourcemaps Gulp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) to map source files of styles.

As far as i know Angular injects component CSS files in HTML `<style>` element. So source mapping seems not to work for this reason.

Do you know any workaround to map CSS? I would figure out why i can't see the source files (`.scss`) in the inspection tools of browsers. What's wrong with sourcemaps plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is nothing we can do at the moment. The feature request is still open on Angular2 Github repository: [enter link description here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9664)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043298) and this article https://medium.com/@IMM9O/angular-cli-some-special-cases-f48059fb33e5

These flags on `ng serve` include sourcemaps.

```
ng serve -sm -ec
```

Or

```
ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss
```

It does not include source maps for the components stylesheets, as you asked, but only for global stylesheets that are included with the `angular-cli.json` config file. It's still better than nothing, especially because when inspecting an element, you can infer that the only CSS that is not mapped to a  source file but to a `<style>` tag is the CSS of the component's stylesheet.

I'm using angular-cli version `1.0.0-rc.4`

Comment: This is obsolete as of 6.x. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318185/how-to-enable-css-sourcemaps-for-angular-6-application for that.