# How to enable CSS sourcemaps for Angular 6 application?

Tags: angular, configuration, source-maps

How do I enable sourcemaps for CSS files in my Angular 6 application?

I'm defining my styles source code in SCSS files, which are later compiled to CSS by Angular CLI. However, I can't see the original source code in the browser during styles debugging. All styles are pointing to the `<style>...</style>` blocks.

I want to be able to see the references to original SCSS files when debugging the compiled code.

What options do I need to set in `angular.json` file?

---

I've tried to use `--source-map` CLI argument for `ng serve` command, but it looks like it's not affecting anything. Sourcemap files are emitted in both cases according to webpack compilation log.

Answer (score 6):

From https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9099#issuecomment-388710635

1) modify angular.json to add --extract-css, in 6.0 this argument is removed from ng serve

```
 "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
       ---
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          ---
        },
        "serve": {
          "extractCss": true,
           ---
        }
      }
    },
```

2) Then change serve->options->browserTarget->project-name:build to project-name:build:serve

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "open": true,
        "browserTarget": "<project-name>:build:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          ---
        }
      }
    }
```

3) run ng serve --source-map

Comment: for me, that `build>configurations>serve` entire node had to be added.  Also you can just look at what the `serve>builder>options>browserTarget` is using and add the `"extractCss": true,` to that node under builder instead of using "serve"